# Prove that there are infinitely many primes which are not Mersenne primes.

Tags: number-theory

Mersenne prime are primes of the form 2^n-1 where n is prime.

Comment: Well, there are infinitely many primes congruent to $1\bmod 4$. And there you have it.

Comment: You can also use that between $n$ and $2n$ there is always a prime for $n\geq 2$. But that fact is somewhat difficult to prove.

Comment: @Mathematician42 Maybe you have heard of Erdos' extremely elementary proof of that fact, which is also called Bertrand's postulate? The proof is really wonderful, I'll attach a link if I find it.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: I never looked up a stand-alone proof. I think it was an exercise to deduce this property from the much stronger prime number theorem. I looked at Edos' proof, it looks elementary enough, I didn't know that there was an elementary proof.

Comment: @Mathematician42 Indeed, right? You might not know that Erdos completed this proof at the age of just 19.

Answer (score 2):

Every Mersenne prime $p$, except $p=3$, satisfies $p\equiv7\pmod{8}$, but there are infinitely many primes $q$ such that (for example) $q\equiv1\pmod{8}$.

Comment: Also 3 mod 8 and 5 mod 8. This follows from Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions.